# how do I translate my query to use with mongodb in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

this is how my mongo query looks like

```
db.test.findOne({"User.David":{$elemMatch:{"action":"todo","status":"Done"}}})
```

I'm implementing this in a node.js api where the user can retrieve docs based on username and status

below is what I've tried.

```
var query = {};
var value = `User.${userName}`;
query[value] = `{$elemMatch:{"action":"todo","status":"${status}"}}`

db.collection(test).findOne(query).then((result)=>{

}
```

problem with this is the query looks like

```
db.test.findOne({'User.David':'{$elemMatch:{"action":"todo","status":"Done"}}'})
```

the quotes are a problem ' ' here.

Comment: Did you try `query[value] = {$elemMatch:{"action":"todo","status":\`${status}\`}}` i.e. not interpolating the whole expression but only the status part?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use a string template around the whole query value expression since that will result in a string.
Instead, just construct your query like so:

```
query[value] = { $elemMatch: { action: "todo", status } }
```

Comment: this resulted in     {'User.David':{'$elemMatch':{action:todo,status:'Done'}}}

Comment: Really? `$elemMatch` is quoted but not `todo`?

Comment: I've edited the answer and simplified the query further